# How can I optimise and improve the speed of this MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to get information from my database and display it. Here is a screenshot of what the page looks like:

[image: Screenshot of grid]

The page loads really slow

Is there any way to make it load and display the data faster?

Here is the code.

```
<table align="center" class="pTable">
<tr class="main"> <th class="pTableHeader"> ID </th> <th class="pTableHeader"> Room </th> <th class="pTableHeader"> Status</th> </tr>
<?php
gc_enable();
gc_collect_cycles();
flush();
$this->mysql = new sqli('HIDDEN','HIDDEN','HIDDEN','HIDDEN');
$bots = $this->mysql->fetch_array("SELECT `pid`,`room`,`id` from `bots`;");
foreach ($bots as $b) { 
if(is_numeric($b["room"])) {
$xat = file_get_contents('http://www.xat.com/xat'.trim($b["room"]));
$name = sp($xat, '<h1>&nbsp;', '</h1>');
}
else $name = $b['room'];
//$b["pid"] = isset($b["pid"])?$b["pid"]:false;
//$online = \"start.php {$b['id']} {$b['id']}\"", $output) && count($output) > 1 ? true : false;
$online = file_exists("/proc/{$b['pid']}" )?true:false;
if($online === true) $status = "<font color='green'>Online</font>&nbsp;<div style='float:right'><img src='http://fexbots.com/Images/Pawns/online.png'>&nbsp;<a href='/botinfo?botid={$b["id"]}'>More info</a></div>";
else $status = "<font color='red'>Offline</font>&nbsp;<div style='float:right'><img src='http://fexbots.com/Images/Pawns/offline.png'>&nbsp;<a  href='/botinfo?botid={$b["id"]}'>More info</a></div>";
if($b["room"] === '') { 
$name = "No Room"; 
$status = "<font color='red'>Not Setup!</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;<div style='float:right'><img src='http://fexbots.com/Images/Pawns/hang.png'>&nbsp;<a  href='/botinfo?botid={$b["id"]}'>More info</a></div>";
echo '<tr> <td> '.$b["id"].' </td> <td> No Room <td> '.$status.'</td> </tr>';
}
else echo "<tr> <td> ".$b['id']." </td> <td> <a href='http://www.xat.com/$name'>$name</a> <td> ".$status."</td> </tr>";
}
function sp($content, $start, $end, $lower=false) {
if($lower!=false) {
$content = strtolower($content);
$start   = strtolower($start);
$end     = strtolower($end);
}
$content = substr($content, strpos($content,$start)+strlen($start));
$content = substr($content, 0, strpos($content,$end));
return $content;
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the query that hinders performance?

Comment: Please indent and format your code because people will be 20x more motivated to help you.

Comment: If I had to gues then `$xat = file_get_contents('http://www.xat.com/xat'.trim($b["room"]));` is the slowdown

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: Yep, my thoughts exactly...

Comment: Try `echo date('H:i:s'); $xat = file_get_contents('http://www.xat.com/xat'.trim($b["room"])); echo date('H:i:s');` to see the time delay

Answer (score 1):

You seem to download the content from an URL inside the loop. Maybe that is the cause to why it is slow and not the mysql query itself.

Try to write out  some timestamps or comment some code out to see what is causing it to be slow.

Comment: Yes it was the file_get_contents, i tested it. How do I fix it? I need to get the download   , also it gave a time delay of, 20:53:4120:53:4320:53:4320:53:4320:53:4320:53:4420:53:4420:53:4520:53:4520:53:4520:53:4520:53:46

Comment: It's hard to lower the loading time if you have to get that data. But you could make it a better user experience for the visitor if you load it using Ajax instead. Then the page will load faster and be visible to the user a lot faster - and when that is done, you can start loading the status for each row using Ajax. You will probably have to create a new PHP page that takes in the $b["room"] as a parameter and then execute file_get_contents in the separate page.